# duda matriz triangular superior c++

Tags: c++, matrices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tenía dudas con el recorrido de la matriz triangular superior, para mí la triangular superior es la de la foto:

```
for (int i=1; i<=m_-1; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<= n_;j++){
```

¿Se podría empezar en i=1? ¿por qué la condición de parada para el primer for es `i<=m_-1`? para no alargar las preguntas, tampoco entiendo el segundo for `int j=i+1; j<= n_`

clase de la que se hace uso:

```
template <class T> class matrix_t
{
private:
 int m_;
 int n_;

 T* v_;
public:
 matrix_t(void);
 matrix_t(int m, int n);
 ~matrix_t(void);

 void resize(int m, int n);
 T& get_set (int i, int j);
 T get (int i, int j) const;
 int get_m(void) const;
 int get_n(void) const;
private:
 int pos(int i, int j) const;
};
```

Gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62843/discussion-between-aer-and-paperbirdmaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Se podría empezar en i=1?

En C++ los índices suelen empezar en 0. Sin embargo en tu código puedes empezar en 1 si así lo prefieres... pero tendrás que tener cuidado para no leer o escribir en posiciones incorrectas.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código:

```
int lista[10];

for( int i=1; i<=10; i++ )
  lista[i] = i;
```

tiene dos errores:

1. Empieza almacenando valores en `lista[1]`, luego `lista[0]` queda sin inicializar
2. Intenta almacenar un valor en `lista[10]`, posición que no pertenece al array

Lo correcto sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
int lista[10];

for( int i=1; i<=10; i++ )
  lista[i-1] = i;
//      ^^^
```

Así que lo mejor suele ser acostumbrarse a iterar en el rango (0,n) y así te quitas de problemas. ya que todos los algoritmos de la librería estándar están pensados para trabajar en ese rango no tendrás que pensar cuándo empezar en 1 y cuando en 0.

> ¿por qué la condición de parada para el primer for es i<=m_-1?

Deberías coger lápiz y papel para simular los algoritmos. Se aprende mucho con eso.

Para iterar la matriz triangular superior tienes que iterar todas las filas y, para cada fila, recorrer las columnas que quedan por encima de la diagonal principal. Empezando en i=0 podría ser así:

```
for( int i=0; i<m_; i++ ) // Iteramos las filas
{
  for( int j=i; j<n_; j++ ) // Iteramos las columnas
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Nota que la diagonal principal la encontramos cuando `i==j`. Si deseamos que el índice de las columnas ignore todo lo que queda detrás de la diagonal principal, entonces tendremos que iniciar dicho bucle en `j=i`.

Ahora bien, el bucle que presentas no parece ser correcto.

```
for (int i=1; i<=m_-1; i++){
  for (int j=i+1; j<= n_;j++){
```

`i` itera en el rango (1,m_-1), es decir, hace `m_-1` iteraciones cuando debería hacer `m_`... se deja una fila por el camino.

El bucle `i` podría ser correcto si quisieses iterar por la zona sombreada de rojo, sin embargo el bucle `j` itera sobre la zona no sombreada... todo apunta a que ese bucle no va a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

La [**matriz triangular superior**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_triangular) es exactamente la que has puesto como imagen.

Tomamos en cuenta que: la matriz esté almacenada en un arreglo bidimensional `matriz[m_][n_]`, que `i` sea el índice que indica la fila y `j` sea el índice que indica la columna, entonces el recorrido de la matriz superior seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < n_; j++)
        std::cout << matriz[i][j] << std::endl;
```

Respondiendo a tus otras preguntas:

- ¿Se podría empezar en `i=1`? Si; el inicio del indice va a depender de como fue almacenada la matriz o desde donde quiere empezar a recorrerla.
- ¿por qué la condición de parada para el primer for es `i<=m_-1`? Quiere decir que `i` puede llegar a ser igual a `m-1`.  Otra forma de escribir esa condición es `i < m_`
- el segundo `for (int j=i+1; j<= n_; j++)`: me atrevería a decir que este *for* va a causar un *segmentation fault* devido a que el indice `j` llega a ser `n_`; pero eso va a depender de como fue almacenada la matriz.

Ayudaría mucho que mostraras como es almacenada la matriz.

Answer (score 0):

Pongo esto, si a alguien le sirve.

```
int isTriangular(int** arr, int r, int c){
    int c1 =0,c2 = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < r; i++ ){
        for(int j =0; j < c; j++){
            if(i == j){
                if(*(*(arr+i)+j) == 0){
                    return 0;//false, ni es superio ni inferior
                    //la diagonal si o si debe tener numeros
                    //diferentes de cero
                }
            }
            if(j > i){
                if(*(*(arr+i)+j) != 0){
                    c1++;
                }
            }else if( j < i){
                if(*(*(arr+i)+j) != 0){
                    c2++;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    if(c1 == 0){
        return -1;//matriz superior
    }else if(c2 == 0){
        return 1;//matriz inferior
    }else{
        return 0;//no es nada
    }
     
}
```